# Como implantar uma aplicação web manualmente no wildfly9?

Tags: java, wildfly

Já implantei uma aplicação web manualmente no tomcat, sei que ele não é um conteiner completo,mas agora gostaria de implantar manualmente no wildfly9 .
Gostaria de implamantar a aplicação web manualmente no wildflyjá porque já tentei rodar pelo netbeans mas não consegui ele diz que a port já esta sendo usada e tal. Já procurei em vários tutorias , mas é tudo meio que antigo.
Se for possivel implantar manualmente  no wildfly, como devo proceder para fazer um teste de implantação usando uma aplicação helloworld que eu implantei no webapp do tomcat para roda no wildfly?
O que eu deveria modificar dentro do diretório  WEB-INF? Precisária mudar alguma coisa no  arquivo standalone.xml  dentro do diretório  do wildfly?

Mensionei o webapp do tomcat existe algo semelhante no wildfly?

Para acessar uma aplicação rodando no tomcat bastaria abrir o browser e digitar o localhost:8080/HelloWorld/index.html como fazer o mesmo no wildfly?

Answer (score 3):

> Se for possível implantar manualmente no wildfly, como devo proceder para fazer um teste de implantação usando uma aplicação *helloworld* que eu implantei no webapp do tomcat para roda no wildfly?

É sim possível. Se estiver usando uma instância *standalone*, basta incluir o artefato a ser implantado em `standalone/deployments`, juntamente com, um marcador para que seja feito a implantação (se o *auto deploy* não estiver habilitado). Então, se o seu artefato se chama `HelloWorld.war`, inclua também um arquivo vazio chamado `HelloWorld.war.dodeploy` (`touch`HelloWorld.war.dodeploy`)

Você pode verificar documentação detalhada aqui: [Application deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Application+deployment?_sscc=t)

É também possível fazer o deploy pela console web de administração, então depois de inicializar o servidor, acesse `http://localhost:9990`, digite usuário e senha (você deverá criar antes usando os scripts `add-user.bat` ou `add-user.sh`), aba **Deployments**, botão **Add** e escolha o tipo e artefato a ser implantado:

[image: Deploy web console]

Aí é só seguir os passos...

> O que eu deveria modificar dentro do diretório WEB-INF? Precisaria mudar alguma coisa no arquivo standalone.xml dentro do diretório do wildfly?

Não sei, precisa? Você depende de alguma coisa provida pelo *container*, como *datasources*, propriedades de sistema customizadas, *thread pool*, *socket bindings*, etc.? Se não, basta alterar o `deployment-scanner` (subsistema `deployment-scanner`) para algo como isto:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
        runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}" 
        scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="false" />
</subsystem>
```

Isto fará com que, no seu caso, `war` colocados em `deployments` sejam implantados, mas não aplicações já descompactadas (para isto, altere `auto-deploy-exploded` para `true`).

A maioria das coisas podem ser configuradas pela web console também, como as propriedades de sistema, *socket bindings*, *datasources*, *mail sessions*, logs, etc.

> Mensionei o webapp do tomcat existe algo semelhante no wildfly?

Sim, como dito acima é por padrão o diretório `deployments` em `standalone`.

> Para acessar uma aplicação rodando no tomcat bastaria abrir o browser e digitar o localhost:8080/HelloWorld/index.html como fazer o mesmo no wildfly?

Se `HelloWorld` é o contexto da aplicação implantada e está usando configurações padrão do WildFly, sim, apenas isto bastará.

Tudo o dito acima pode ser feito pela CLI, então considere ler sobre ela: [CLI Recipes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/CLI+Recipes)

Em caso de problemas, seja mais específico na sua dúvida :)

Comment: obrigado pela paciencia ! É que a documentação indicada não é tão didatica para iniciantes .Vou retirara foto, só queria que você visse. Por que quando a abro browser ele não roda? http://localhost:8083/HelloWorld/index.html   = not found

Comment: @PenaPintada por que o artefato implantado tem outro nome, se olhar na pasta `deployments` verá que terá a versão no nome.

Comment: O wildfly vem com algums exemplos prontos assim como o tomcat?

Comment: @PenaPintada sim, o quickstart tem muita coisa: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart

Comment: @PenaPintada e aí, conseguiu? Alguma dúvida quanto a isto ainda?

Comment: Valeu amigo.Ainda não, desisti porque ia perder muito tempo, esotu me virando com o  glassfish!! Tenho uns projetos para entregar !! Depois volto ao wildfly! Qualquer coisa te procuro ,brother!